# Phpmyadmin not working after upgrading to PHP

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just upgraded to PHP7, but phpmyadmin has stopped working. I have followed lots of steps that I found on the internet but it is still not working.

What I keep getting is:

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: 500 is a server error, it doesn't really tell us anything else.  You'll need to add the output of your apache error log.  Most likely it's located at /var/log/apache/error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: this is error: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 77

Answer (score 3):

This solves it:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I had the issue with 16.04. mbstring and gettext were missing.

Comment: Exactly. Not until I checked the error log as advised by @bc2946088